# What does this schematic symbol mean? (triangle with a line crossing it out)

Tags: schematics, symbol

I found the following circuit symbol in an [MSP430 User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=slau144) in the section describing the ADC:

[image: weird symbol]

(I made a red circle around it)

What does it represent?

Comment: Never seen that before, don't know what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: Perhaps it's a [deluminator](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Deluminator).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The diagram on page 631 of the user guide has it labeled "Temp. Sensor".

This is the internal Block Diagram for the SD24_A ADC, but it's almost functionally the same for the other ADC Types

[image]

Comment: It's a Temperature Sensing Diode. Listed as a diode on Page 592 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen varactor symbols that look similar, but they always have two parallel lines at the top of the triangle. A triangle pointing upwards can also be used to represent a power plane, but that doesn't make sense due to both it's location, the line through it, and the current source directly above it.

Is there a legend somewhere in the document that might explain it? Also, if we had an image of the entire schematic someone might be able to piece together what it might be.